What information does the Schatten norm contain about an operator?
Let $H_1. H_2$ be Hilbert spaces and $T: H_1 \rightarrow H_2$ a bounded linear operator. For $p \in [1,\infty)$ the Schatten $p$-norm is defined as
$$\|T\|_p = \big[Tr\big((T^*T)^p\big)\big]^{1/p}.$$
Familiar examples are $p = 1$ (trace class norm), $p = 2$ (Hilber-Schmidt norm), and the special case $p = \infty$ (operator norm).
For integrable functions we define $L^p$ spaces where the different values of $p$ quantify the function's decay at infinity and/or its singular behavior. In an analogy to these functions, does the Schatten norm tell you anything about the behavior of an operator?

$$|T|_p=[Tr(T^*T)^{p/2}]^{1/p}$$ The norm is equal  to the $\ell^p$-norm of the sequence of the eigenvalues (with multiplicities) of $|T|=(T^*T)^{1/2}.$

@RyszardSzwarc Does $\ell^p$ norm of the eigenvalues tell you anything about the operator, at least qualitatively?
